# Couldn't compile C program after update to macOS Mojave

Tags: c, macos, gcc, mpi, macos-mojave

I've just updated my OS version to Mojave today and all of a sudden, I'm not able to compile any C/mpi program in the terminal. I'm getting this error message stating:

```
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0/8.1.0/include- 
fixed/stdio.h:78:10:fatal error: _stdio.h: No such file or directory
#include <_stdio.h>
```

I'm not sure why but when I enter /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86... there is a file named stdio.h so I'm not sure why is this happening all of a sudden. Would like to know how do I resolve this issue.

I tried performing `xcode-select --install` prompts that I looked up but nothing changed.

Comment: The `gcc` compiler you are using was likely installed via **homebrew**, so you need to do `brew upgrade gcc`

Comment: There is a solution to this problem in the comments to the later question, [Can't compile C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave).