# Netbeans on mac for C not working after updating to Mojave

Tags: c, macos, netbeans, macos-mojave

We use Netbeans for C language at school. Everything was working fine; updated to os Mojave, now it will not compile and I receive the following:

```
cd '/Users/zacheryharper/NetBeansProjects/Ch6HWZacheryHarper'
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Comment: Amongst others, see [Can't compile C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave) — the information there may well help you on your way.  It doesn't discuss NetBeans specifically, but it covers similar ground.  I do have `/usr/bin/xcrun` on my Mojave Mac now.

Comment: how do I get it working or put on there?

Comment: You get (download) XCode from the App Store and install it.  You can then run the GUI to accept terms and download more.  You may then need to use `xcode-select —install` to install (and download?) the command line tools.  And then you need to install the extra package discussed in the answer to the linked question.