# PyStan: CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 (macos)

Tags: python, pystan

This is a PyStan model that I am trying to run. However, once I try to run it I come across the following error:

CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Any idea how this error could be fixed on the macOS?

```
counts = [0.0711, 0.125, 0.0121, 0.00513, 0.112, 0.0694, 0.0166, 0.163, 0.0481, 0.0762, 0.175, 0.117, 0.211, 0.0468, 0.0272, 0.134, 0.035, 0.0125, 0.0834, 0.011, 0.0226, 0.0652, 0.132, 0.0738, 0.206, 0.107, 0.0354, 0.0853, 0.0219, 0.106, 0.165, 0.0729, 0.111, 0.0352, 0.0749, 0.00188, 0.00146, 0.0113, 0.0175, 0.167, 0.0736, 0.00292, 0.0378, 0.116, 0.145, 0.161, 0.292, 0.0158, 0.207, 0.481, 0.066, 0.0926, 0.0188, 0.103, 0.262, 0.167, 0.163, 0.0357, 0.137, 0.0699, 0.00632, 0.012, 0.124, 0.159, 0.000179, 0.0441, 0.16, 0.196, 0.131, 0.0731, 0.0282, 0.046, 0.089, 0.0318, 0.0303, 0.0269, 0.184, 0.144, 0.0981, 0.277, 0.0277, 0.000416, 0.225, 0.0538, 0.0422, 0.186, 0.00116, 0.0118, 0.0668, 0.157, 0.12, 0.0285, 0.0204, 0.0702, 0.0692, 0.126, 0.00857, 0.0322, 0.029, 0.0737, 0.0811, 0.0172, 0.121, 0.0589, 0.00973, 0.0797, 0.0996, 0.0862, 0.185, 0.0671, 0.0142, 0.0669, 0.0739, 0.12, 0.566, 0.0179, 0.0483, 0.0382, 0.0109, 0.058, 0.0252, 0.0368, 0.0241, 0.156, 0.0696, 0.015, 0.0759, 0.0431, 0.0798, 0.0816, 0.108, 0.0155, 0.0211, 0.00171, 0.00148, 0.0117, 0.0164, 0.0681, 0.000238, 0.00691, 0.127, 0.0502, 0.00598, 0.0722, 0.0174, 0.0627, 0.00372, 0.0648, 0.0343, 0.101, 0.0751, 0.0111, 0.189, 0.0298, 0.0563, 0.0123, 0.00126, 0.0407, 0.0203, 0.143, 0.0488, 0.0696, 0.0145, 0.0474, 0.0245, 0.172, 0.17, 0.109, 0.182, 0.0357, 0.0729, 0.295, 0.041, 0.207, 0.0725, 0.107, 0.00257, 0.0252, 0.0866, 0.00576, 0.0468, 0.13, 0.0881, 0.115, 0.0321, 0.000605, 0.0392, 0.017, 0.0408, 0.00253, 0.132, 0.298, 0.109, 0.00814, 0.0338, 0.0253, 0.0153, 0.0475, 0.0624, 0.199, 0.265, 0.0202, 0.199, 0.135, 0.0285, 0.0728, 0.124, 0.0165, 0.0385, 0.0843, 0.0988, 0.139, 0.0311, 0.0837, 0.0931, 0.182, 0.0129, 0.00582, 0.0166, 0.109, 0.039, 0.0892, 0.0269, 0.0407, 0.154, 0.109, 0.212, 0.112, 0.0252, 0.00368, 0.0556, 0.103, 0.0754, 0.0135, 0.106, 0.184, 0.0462, 0.0152, 0.0438, 0.105, 0.0283, 0.0417, 0.229, 0.103, 0.0628, 0.0499, 0.122, 0.0227, 0.0451, 0.164, 0.121, 0.0665, 0.00797, 0.113, 0.0421, 0.166, 0.062, 0.129, 0.0966, 0.0167, 0.211, 0.0155, 0.129, 0.0595, 0.0219, 0.105, 0.0483, 0.0959, 0.064, 0.00275, 0.166, 0.0134, 0.0549, 0.235, 0.06, 0.000117, 0.00322, 0.0557, 0.0555, 0.169, 0.211, 0.0521, 0.0485, 0.0173, 0.0644, 0.109, 0.043, 0.0111, 0.215, 0.114, 0.0552, 0.00457, 0.219, 0.314, 0.049, 0.0113, 0.0513, 0.151, 0.00505, 0.0232, 0.0637, 0.0347, 0.0247, 0.000251, 0.0439, 0.00442, 0.124, 0.115, 0.0601, 0.209, 0.422, 0.0646, 0.00895, 0.047, 0.125, 0.0196, 0.187, 0.0125, 0.00415, 0.0394, 0.035, 0.046, 0.0236, 0.0551, 0.152, 0.0371, 0.00205, 0.0499, 0.0565, 0.0341, 0.0509, 0.0589, 0.0456, 0.0365, 0.00266, 0.0681, 0.0565, 0.0045, 0.0144, 0.0601, 0.0303, 0.0349, 0.0441, 0.0328, 0.0733, 0.0488, 0.0717, 0.269, 0.0997, 0.0157, 0.00706, 0.0426, 0.149, 0.0473, 0.0846, 0.0519, 0.0223, 0.0848, 0.0145, 0.00368, 5.87e-05, 0.0163, 0.0841, 0.171, 0.0538, 0.0445, 0.147, 0.0236, 0.115, 0.193, 0.00451, 0.014, 0.0687, 0.00123, 0.13, 0.0513, 0.0662, 0.15, 0.133, 0.0459, 0.0777, 0.0442, 0.106, 0.0114, 0.00198, 0.00188, 0.105, 0.155, 0.098, 0.0762, 0.12, 0.00772, 0.0203, 0.0309, 0.0198, 0.0654, 0.106, 0.0853, 0.000944, 0.000954, 0.109, 0.0293, 0.0693, 0.0262, 0.0767, 0.307, 0.0163, 0.0962, 0.0224, 0.00329, 0.00259, 0.0164, 0.0481, 0.194, 0.00661, 0.111, 0.00302, 0.154, 0.00364, 0.0176, 0.0554, 0.0916, 0.0313, 0.0198, 0.121, 0.145, 0.0539, 0.101, 0.127, 0.0408, 0.0882, 0.0538, 0.0717, 0.104, 0.113, 0.00819, 0.146, 0.000258, 0.0787, 0.115, 0.0136, 0.0367, 0.0852, 0.0565, 0.0666, 0.105, 0.0834, 0.0789, 0.0496, 0.0952, 0.0742, 0.0143, 0.0627, 0.0164, 0.079, 0.021, 0.0803, 0.000524, 0.0245, 0.0097, 0.0599, 0.0469, 0.0176, 0.0708, 0.0731, 0.0614, 0.085, 0.0221, 0.191, 0.00177, 0.0272, 0.0567, 0.0255, 0.00566, 0.122, 0.15, 0.0715, 0.0338, 0.0193, 0.00552, 0.0457, 0.208, 0.174, 0.0026, 0.0656, 0.0742, 0.022, 0.0382, 0.172, 0.0209, 0.04, 0.117, 0.0217, 0.000618, 0.0459, 0.00841, 0.0104, 0.0509, 0.104, 0.000327, 0.0042, 0.0902, 0.0341, 0.091, 0.0569, 0.027, 0.184, 0.0343, 0.19, 0.00992, 0.111, 0.225, 0.0608, 0.0927, 0.0617, 0.0808, 0.00346, 0.161, 0.055, 0.105, 0.506, 0.0304, 0.0163, 0.0973, 0.000753, 0.0564, 0.0032, 0.00947, 0.0337, 0.0905, 0.0918, 0.0315, 0.0155, 0.0425, 0.00194, 0.00797, 0.103, 0.000849, 0.00948, 0.0641, 0.0765, 0.0982, 0.00755, 0.0969, 0.0585, 0.102, 0.012, 0.0807, 0.181, 0.255, 0.0239, 0.00207, 0.00591, 0.0988, 0.0383, 0.204, 0.0168, 0.0487, 0.0326, 0.0457, 0.0212, 0.0192, 0.185, 0.0876, 0.00121, 0.0229, 0.023, 0.0986, 0.0831, 0.0192, 0.142, 0.00611, 0.0369, 0.0496, 0.0523, 0.0471, 0.0315, 0.0202, 0.0342, 0.00263, 0.307, 0.0354, 0.0234, 0.133, 0.124, 0.0744, 0.114, 0.102, 0.0694, 0.0626, 0.0245, 0.00579, 0.124, 0.171, 0.212, 0.0113, 0.00475, 0.00489, 0.0727, 0.0388, 0.0584, 0.207, 0.0665, 0.143, 0.0714, 0.192, 0.197, 0.053, 0.0309, 0.0151, 0.0495, 0.0143, 0.0837, 0.138, 0.00898, 0.195, 0.0225, 0.0251, 0.0159, 0.121, 0.0887, 0.0277, 0.0282, 0.162, 0.018, 0.28, 0.00839, 0.0286, 0.0063, 0.0313, 0.021, 0.0609, 0.00187, 0.00668, 0.0366, 0.0598, 0.0707, 0.174, 0.109, 0.0608, 0.0313, 0.109, 0.0132, 0.087, 0.00677, 0.018, 0.044, 0.017, 0.158, 0.0442, 0.114, 0.0673, 0.0326, 0.031, 0.0724, 0.14, 0.0186, 0.00151, 0.0302, 0.0386, 0.201, 0.00411, 0.00878, 0.0313, 0.000188, 0.0748, 0.0779, 0.00582, 0.07, 0.0113, 0.00965, 0.151, 0.0443, 0.011, 0.0381, 0.00801, 0.0203, 0.164, 0.0242, 0.0217, 0.0261, 0.0627, 0.000245, 0.0106, 0.00567, 0.0736, 0.02, 0.0391, 0.0105, 0.0925, 0.00756, 0.0102, 0.013, 0.00146, 0.088, 0.0247, 0.063, 0.00596, 0.0107, 0.0358, 0.013, 0.0117, 0.0256, 0.0265, 0.368, 0.00302, 0.00357, 0.0419, 0.0245, 0.0563, 0.109, 0.0796, 0.109, 0.0567, 0.0207, 0.00938, 0.256, 0.0557, 0.113, 0.011, 0.00809, 0.0214, 0.00244, 0.0161, 0.0297, 0.128, 0.0223, 0.0113, 0.0275, 0.0196, 0.0121, 0.0773, 0.0428, 0.0674, 0.0116, 0.0186, 0.129, 0.146, 0.0766, 0.000269, 0.0149, 0.0493, 0.00883, 0.00656, 0.00548, 0.0193, 0.00948, 0.0633, 0.0361, 0.0742, 0.0427, 0.0274, 0.0539, 0.027, 0.0145, 0.0388, 0.0271, 0.0036, 0.0812, 0.0378, 0.0195, 0.0164, 0.0615, 0.101, 0.0605, 0.0494, 0.0609, 0.0538, 0.0205, 0.0187, 0.0147, 0.00858, 0.0905, 0.196, 0.0792, 0.0445, 0.0575, 0.0126, 0.173, 0.0379, 0.104, 0.0854, 0.0465, 0.145, 0.00447, 0.0506, 0.0499, 0.0213, 0.0521, 0.0466, 0.0131, 0.0197, 0.0454, 0.00161, 0.0168, 0.00849, 0.0663, 0.0081, 0.00594, 0.0428, 0.0157, 0.102, 0.0309, 0.0543, 0.0236, 0.0154, 0.0214, 0.106, 0.00881, 0.226, 0.0497, 0.0386, 0.0864, 0.0155, 0.139, 0.116, 0.0409, 0.0534, 0.0877, 0.022, 0.0179, 0.0112, 0.0302, 0.0123, 0.11, 7.21e-06, 0.111, 0.0548, 0.127, 0.00477, 0.13, 0.00288, 0.0602, 0.147, 0.0207, 0.132, 0.00212, 0.0246, 0.0776, 0.0598, 0.114, 0.0272, 0.0079, 0.0285, 0.0111, 0.103, 0.296, 0.0313, 0.0384, 0.00446, 0.0657, 0.0114, 0.342, 0.0434, 0.0266, 0.109, 0.00581, 0.0155, 0.0322, 0.046, 0.0816, 0.056, 0.0124, 0.0329, 0.126, 0.0381, 0.0393, 0.0154, 0.00345, 0.00226, 0.114, 0.0881, 0.00316, 0.0388, 0.111, 0.0139, 0.0205, 0.0119, 0.0705, 0.0219, 0.0765, 0.0729, 0.0485, 0.00661, 0.169, 0.00679, 0.0538, 0.00537, 0.01, 0.047, 0.0325, 0.0668]



stan_code = """

 data {
   int<lower=1> C;    // number of calls in 11th
   real<lower=0> alpha;   // prior hyperparameters for gamma
   real<lower=0> beta;   // prior hyperparameters for gamma
   real<lower=0> counts[C];   
}

parameters {
    real<lower=0> lambda; 
}


model {
   lambda ~ gamma(alpha,beta);
   counts ~ exponential(lambda);   
   }
"""

stan_model = pystan.StanModel(model_code=stan_code)

stan_data = {
   'C': 892,
   'alpha': [0.5],
   'beta': [0.5],
   'counts': counts,
}

results = stan_model.sampling(data=stan_data)

print(results)
```

Comment: search how to install `gcc` on your machine.

Comment: Everybody always refers to conda. Looking for non-conda solution.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem. I solved it using conda. Suppose you've created a conda environment called pystan. Activate it, and then install gcc:

```
    $ source activate pystan
(pystan)$ conda install gcc
```

Then make sure you install pystan's [dependencies](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#prerequisites), and pip-install pystan

```
(pystan)$ pip install pystan
```

These steps solve the problem in my case, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

`gcc -v` showed that my gcc version is 4.2.x, and [Stan 2.19.0.0 requires gcc 4.9.3 or higher](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whats_new.html). So I installed gcc49 using Homebrew:

```
$ brew install gcc49
```

If `gcc -v` still doesn't print 4.9.x, but `gcc-4.9 -v` does, then you should create a link to the `gcc` and `g++` executables you just installed:

```
$ sudo ln -s `which gcc-4.9` /usr/local/bin/gcc
$ sudo ln -s `which g++-4.9` /usr/local/bin/g++
```

The following step is probably not needed, but as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52530212/8424390), on reasonably new macOS and Xcode you should also execute the following installer (at least if you use the compiler that comes with Xcode which we don't):

```sh
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

I use PyStan in a Conda environment, installed as such:

```
$ conda create -n pystan python=3.7
$ conda activate pystan
(pystan) $ pip install pystan
```

The order of the above steps might matter.

Comment: For me the linking doesn't work, when I call gcc -v it always uses the xcode c++ version (which is 4.2.1)

Comment: To be more precise even though the linking is successful, when I run `gcc -v` I do not get the same output as `gcc-4.9 -v`

Comment: Also I have been using `conda` which seems to use an own version of clang so it is important to install `pystan` using the `conda-forge` channel and not using `pip`! Hope this helps others in the future (I know this question was specifically *not* about `conda`).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone (like me) very lost and finding their way here, this is what worked for me...

System:

```
OS: macOS Big Sur v11.3
pystan.__version__ '2.19.1.1'
Python 3.8.8
```

#### Problem

I was getting a `CompileError` when running:

```
import pystan
model_code = 'parameters {real y;} model {y ~ normal(0,1);}'
model = pystan.StanModel(model_code=model_code)  # this will take a minute
y = model.sampling(n_jobs=1).extract()['y']
y.mean()  # should be close to 0
```

#### Solution

1. Ensure gcc & xcode version installed & up-to-date (`brew install gcc && xcode-select --install`)
2. As per [this thread](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/python-3-7-pystan-19-0-0-error-distutilsexecerror-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1/8636) check gcc and g++ version by running `ls /usr/local/bin | grep gcc` and `ls /usr/local/bin | grep g++` and add these as env variables. In my case I added these lines to my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
# for c++ libraries - reqiured for pystan / prophet
export CC=gcc-11
export CXX=g++-11
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would be helpful for others, what worked at the end for me was to install python3 and run this code in terminal

source activate py36
jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

If you are using Mac M1 and due to some files corrupt or delete, you get this issue while you have gcc installed you can use this and then run the installation of the package.

My case it was detectron2 in a new env