# Using GCC in -m32 mode on mac OS

Tags: macos, gcc, configuration

I need to use gcc in -m32 mode on my macOS Mojave. I know it was deprecated some time ago. What should I do to make it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to download an older version of Xcode (eg. `9.x`), and pre `10.14` SDK's (eg. `10.13`), then try from there. Apple dropped Xcode capability/support for `i386` in `10.14`. In other words, Mojave can run existing `32-bit` applications but can't build `32-bit` applications anymore.

↳ [MacPorts Discussion : User information about macOS Mojave](https://macports-users.macosforge.narkive.com/2Ze2RUGr/user-information-about-macos-mojave)

Answer (score 0):

Works for me by installing:

`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`

as commented here: [Can't compile C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave/52530212#comment91963866_52509602)