# Semantic issue - Implicitly declaring library function 'printf' with type 'int (const char *, ...)'

Tags: c, xcode, stdio

I can't figure out why I'm getting the warning ⚠️

Using Xcode 11.1 the default Xcode compiler MacOS Catalina.

> Implicitly declaring library function 'printf' with type 'int (const char *, ...)'
>
> Include the header  or explicitly provide a declaration for 'printf'

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ){
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

The **header**  was included.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94CDN.png)

Something is wrong with the Xcode on the new MacOS Catalina? I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code is correct. There must be a problem with your toolset/compiler/IDE/setup.

Comment: I think there are specific issues with header files under the latest MacOS 'Catalina'.  Apple seems to have changed/rearranged some things. There have been several similar questions over the past couple of days.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278260/cant-compile-a-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrading-to-catalina-10-15).

Comment: @SteveSummit So we'll have to wait until they fix it ...