# Mac Catalina pip3 cannot find header file stdio.h

Tags: python, macos, vim, header

Tried to install pynvim. Cannot solve the problem using Xcode-select --install command

Comment: Please find information here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278260/cant-compile-a-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrading-to-catalina-10-15

Comment: Please find information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278260/cant-compile-a-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrading-to-catalina-10-15

Comment: In the future it would be helpful for you to post the steps you took to reproduce the error as well as failed attempts at solving the problem.  Additionally, any errors encountered will help people steer you toward the solution.