# R Archived Package "OC" (Optimal Classification) Installation Failed Due to gcc Issues

Tags: r, macos, gcc, gfortran

**EDIT**: My OS is 10.15.4 and R is 4.0.0 and Xcode 11.4.1

I tried to install an archived package "OC" (Optimal Classification). I downloaded the file from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/oc/) (oc_1.01.tar.gz) first and store it on my desktop. I have tried to install this through `install.packages("oc_1.01.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")`  or `install_version("oc", version = "1.01", repos = "https://cran.r-project.org/")` and it always failed with warnings as:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [oc.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘oc’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/oc’
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/yv/gzy_ljk971d4jnlntnfvht_40000gn/T//Rtmpr8pJmf/remotes1e1745dfa9dc/oc’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have tried several solutions similar to [this](https://medium.com/biosyntax/following-up-library-dependency-when-compiling-r-packages-89f191b9f227) to download gcc or gcc@8 through Homebrew and made changes on the file `Makeconf`. However, as long as I made changes (even I restored the original codes), installation still fails and returns warnings as:

```
R clang: error: no such file or directory: 'SHLIB_LIBADD'
R clang: error: no such file or directory: '='
```

If I changed `CC`, `CXX` (including all `CXX` related such as `CXX17`), and `FLIBS` to `gcc-8` or `gcc-9`, the returned warnings become:

```
R gcc-8: error: no such file or directory: 'SHLIB_LIBADD'
R gcc-8: error: no such file or directory: '='
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I had no problem compiling version 1.01 from source with your `devtools::install_version` call on macOS 10.14.6. What version of macOS are you using? Have you already [installed the SDK headers](https://donatstudios.com/MojaveMissingHeaderFiles)? If so, please provide the contents of `~/.R/Makevars`.

Comment: @IanCampbell, thanks for your reply. My OS is 10.15.4 and R is 4.0.0. I am uninstalling and re-installing Command Line Tools as the instructions in the comments. It turns out I do not have the folder `Packages` so I keep getting errors. Also, I have tried to find out `~/.R/Makevars` but I cannot find it.

Comment: If re-installing command line tools doesn't work for you, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58349403/13095326). And if that doesn't work, check out [this blog post](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/).

Comment: @IanCampbell, I uninstall Xcode, R, and Homebrew first, and them re-install Xcode and follow [your first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278260/cant-compile-a-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrading-to-catalina-10-15/58349403#58349403). It looks like the SDK headers were installed. However, while I install `devtools`, there are several warnings. When I tried to install `OC`, it still failed and returned many warnings and then says `make: gfortran: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @IanCampbell, regardless of those warnings, I finally installed `OC` on my laptop. After the actions in the previous comment, I downloaded gfortran-8.2-Mojave.dmg from [here](https://mac.r-project.org/tools/) and installed it, and then execute `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gfortran/bin` to add `/usr/local/gfortran/bin` to my PATH. It still returns many warnings but it is installed now.