# Mac freezes when running compiles c application

Tags: c, macos, gcc, clang

For a long time I have been trying to compile and run c programs on my MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina, I’ve tried compiling with cc, gcc and clang and the compilation seems to work just fine but every time I run the .out file my Mac freezes, I can’t control+c out of the application and even if I terminate the terminal the issue continues with the finder app (it completely stops responding), so in order to fix the problem I have to completely shut the computer off and then turn it on again via the power button.
This issue happens with every program that I have tried, including the “hello, world” program.

I have compiled a minimal test with `gcc -v -o demo demo.c` and the output is:

```
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.15.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name demo.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mframe-pointer=all -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=10.15.4 -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 556.6 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -Wno-objc-signed-char-bool-implicit-int-conversion -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/user -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.15.0 -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/xj/rw_jny791d9c83w_rplgscnw0000gn/T/demo-635cdc.o -x c demo.c
clang -cc1 version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62) default target x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -platform_version macos 10.15.0 10.15.4 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o demo /var/folders/xj/rw_jny791d9c83w_rplgscnw0000gn/T/demo-635cdc.o -L/usr/local/lib -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

Comment: So it does this even with a "Hello World" program? _"the issue continues with the finder"_, what is this supposed to mean? Please [edit] and elaborate.

Comment: Compile a "helloworld.c" with `gcc -v -o helloworld helloworld.c` and paste here the output, maybe we can see something suspicious.

Comment: For completeness: `int main(void) { puts("Hi"); return 0; }`

Comment: Searching your message complaining about `ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/...` in Google I have found [Can't compile a C program on a Mac after upgrading to Catalina 10.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278260/cant-compile-a-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrading-to-catalina-10-15).

Comment: @GiotlabOffice please put all relevant information __into the question__. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Thank you @DavidRanieri, you’ve solved my issue.

Comment: @GiotlabOffice I'm glad to hear that

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to run this command:

```
export CPATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/
```

For anyone else that experiences this issue, please see discussion at: [Can't compile a C program on a Mac after upgrading to Catalina 10.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278260/cant-compile-a-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrading-to-catalina-10-15)