# Strange behaviour of CXX variable in CMake, breaks boost installation on MacOS Catalina

Tags: xcode, macos, boost, cmake, b2

Our team is working on a new release of a scientific C++ library.
However, we encountered a problem on MacOS Catalina when trying to include boost with CMake that we are unable to understand in its entirety.

First, I will described the problem in more detail. At the end, I will provide a minimal working example that, from my understanding, summarizes the problem.

#### Big-picture goal

Our big picture goal is to use the **boost library** in our software package. For that, we use [**B2**](https://github.com/boostorg/build) inside our CMakeFile. Our `boost.cmake` is based on [this file](https://github.com/pfultz2/cget/blob/master/cget/cmake/boost.cmake). The problem occurs already when calling `bootstrap.sh`.

#### Problem

B2 checks whether the local compiler is able to execute a simple c++11 file (this happens in [`build.sh`](https://github.com/boostorg/build/blob/develop/src/engine/build.sh), the executed cxx file is [`check_cxx11.cpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/build/blob/develop/src/engine/check_cxx11.cpp)).
This seems to work out-of-the-box on Linux systems. **On macOS Catalina however, this fails due to not finding `<wchar.h>`**:

```
In file included from check_cxx11.cpp:14:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:86:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:95:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:118:15: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found
#include_next <wchar.h>
```

However, if I compile the cpp example with clang++ or g++ out of the terminal, I get no errors.

I was able to find out that the problem is due to the `CXX` environmental variable which has been set to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++` by CMake (already with the line `project(test LANGUAGES CXX)`).

The error does occur when `CXX` is undefined before calling CMake. If I export `CXX=/usr/bin/clang++` before executing Cmake, the same error occurs. **However, if I export `CXX=/usr/bin/g++`, everything works fine**.

#### Reproducability

I was able to reproduce this issue on a clean installation of macOS Catalina (10.15.7), where only CMake and xcode have been installed, so I am certain that this is not only a problem on my machine but a general issue on at least this specific OSX version.

#### Minimal (not)-working-example

Since I found out that this issue is related to the `CXX` variable, I created a minimal working example that should summarize this issue.

My *CMakeLists.txt* looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.3)
project(test LANGUAGES CXX)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
include(boost)
```

*boost.cmake*:

```
message(STATUS "CXX: " $ENV{CXX})

execute_process(COMMAND sh ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build_file.sh $ENV{CXX}
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

*build_shell.sh*:

```
$1 -x c++ -std=c++11 check_cxx11.cpp
```

check_cxx11.cpp:

```
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    // Check for basic thread calls.
    { auto _ = std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); }
}
```

If I do not export `CXX` before running cmake, the output is

```
-- CXX: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
```

and the code fails.

If I export `CXX=/usr/bin/clang++`, the output is

```
-- CXX: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang++
```

and the code fails.

If I export `CXX=/usr/bin/g++`, the output is

```
-- CXX: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/g++
```

and the code works.

#### Question

We would like to understand why this happens: Why does CMake change the `CXX` variable to be (apparently) wrong? Why does the code work with g++, but not with clang++?

The installation process should work out-of-the-box for MacOS users, without having to export any environmental variables. It would be nice to fix this problem by understanding the problem and not by just hardcoding something that just *somehow makes the code work*.

Comment: "Why does CMake change the CXX variable to be (apparently) wrong?" - Probably, CMake treats the compiler `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang++` **valid**. So, nothing wrong in setting `CXX` environment variable to that value. You may also check value of CMake variable `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` after the `project()` call: value of that variable denotes a compiler used by CMake. If CMake works with the compiler successfully, but Boost doesn't work, then the problem is not with CMake but with Boost, is it?

Comment: @Tsyvarev `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` is set to the same path as `CXX`. All the compilers under the path `Library/Developer/.../` are working in general, therefore CMake is not complaining. But the library that boost needs (thread) is not working with these compilers (or at least with clang++), therefore the error occurs.

This may very well be a boost issue, but it might also be an xcode issue or just something we need to consider in our CMakeFile.

Comment: The thing that you cannot compile a single c++ file smells like you have some problems with `clang` **settings**, so it cannot find standard C headers like `wchar.h` or `stdio.h` (do not confuse with C++ standard library). See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278260/cant-compile-a-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrading-to-catalina-10-15/58278392#58278392) about such problem and ways how to resolve it.