# Include files not found even with correct -I / gcc + mac os

Tags: macos, gcc, include-path

`gcc` apparently cannot find the include file in the specified place.  It does work if I use

```
#include "fullpath/stdint.h"
```

I can't get it to work using

```
#include < stdint.h >
```

I tried compiling a package using `gcc` on Mac OS.  No success.  I nailed the problem to the include file `stdint.h`.

I wrote the following test code:

```
// 1 #include <stdint.h>
// 2 #include "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h"
// 3 typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
uint64_t x ;

x = 10 ;

printf("x = %lld\n",x);
}
```

If I uncomment the first commented out line, labeled as "1", it won't work.

I tried compiling with:

```
> gcc -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/ test.c
test.c:8:9: error: expected ';' after expression
uint64_t x ;
        ^
        ;
test.c:8:1: error: use of undeclared identifier 'uint64_t'
uint64_t x ;
^
```

I also tried setting the `GCC_INCLUDE_DIR` and `C_INCLUDE_DIR` environment variables to no avail:

```
> env | grep INCLUDE C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/
GCC_INCLUDE_PATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/
> gcc test.c
test.c:8:9: error: expected ';' after expression
uint64_t x ;
        ^
        ;
test.c:8:1: error: use of undeclared identifier 'uint64_t'
uint64_t x ;
```

Now, if I use either the 2 or 3 commented out lines the program compiles and runs just fine.

So it must be some problem finding the `stdint.h` file.  Is there something wrong with my use of `-I`?  I re-read this line a thousand times, added a space after `-I`, took the space out, nothing seems to help.  The same happens with the environment variables.

`gcc` and Mac OS versions:

```
> uname -a
Darwin Antonios-MacBook-Pro.local 18.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.5.0: Mon Mar 11 20:40:32 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.251.3~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

> gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Adding the include `#include <stdint.h>` it works and gives the result `x = 10` on macOS Mojave. Any special configuration you are using?

Comment: Thanks Stephan, well, I use yadr/zsh, but in principle using gcc - I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/ should overcome anything funny yadr/zsh does.  Also, I have tried compiling under csh as well as bash, it is always the same :-(

Comment: Perhaps the following link is useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave

Comment: YESSS!  really useful.  Thanks very much.