# stdio.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, xcode, macos, gcc, stdio

I got the foll. error compiling a simple `ciao.c program`

```
 In file included from ciao.c:1:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0/8.3.0/include-fixed/stdio.h:78:10: fatal error: _stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I've already installed Xcode, command line tools and what you want, but nope.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: use this `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: Check [Can't compile C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave/52530212#52530212) — it will likely help you.

Comment: You seem to be using a 'real' `gcc` (as opposed to the `gcc` from XCode which is actually `clang` in disguise (`/usr/bin/gcc --version` likely produces `Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8) — Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0` or something similar (that's from XCode 11.0).  The error message is from 'real' GCC.  It suggests that there is a problem in `/usr/include` — there are three files `_stdio.h` under `/usr/include` on my machine (in `/usr/include`, `/usr/include/xlocale` and `/usr/include/secure`) — and maybe the other question will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Rename `<_stdio.h>` to `<stdio.h>`.

P.S. Here is an updated answer to the updated question:

Try reinstalling Xcode using `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: there is no <_stdio.h>

Answer (score 3):

**I actually have the same issue that you have;here is the step, follow it, it may help you**

**choose 1:** Copy and paste the following every time you open the terminal

```
export CPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

**choose 2:**  If the choose 1 is working then:

**Step-1:** Paste the following code in terminal:

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

**Step-2:** Open a new terminal, paste the following code:

```
open /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0/8.3.0/include-fixed/
```

**Step-3:** copy All file file from **step-1**, the direction(include) you have open -> paste in the **step-2**, the direction(include-fixed) you open

**Step 4:** When it asks you about whether to REPLACE the file or not, choose to replace.