# installed gcc and g++ on Mac mojave is not working (brew install)

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, homebrew

I installed gcc by brew on Mac OS mojave, but both of gcc and g++ are not working.

I tried compile below simple code by g++ but I got error messages.

This program can be compiled correctly by default clang,
so I am wondering there is any library link error.
But I am not sure.

I got same error in the case of gcc.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    cout << i * 2 + 1 << endl;
}
```

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd,
>   file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21
>   0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not
>   the architecture being linked (x86_64):
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "___cxa_atexit",
>   referenced from:
>         __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccEBCemd.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2:
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status

g++ -v says

> Using built-in specs.
>   COLLECT_GCC=g++
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.2.0/lto-wrapper
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18
>   Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin18 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_1 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_1/lib/gcc/9 --disable-nls --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-9 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 9.2.0_1' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --disable-multilib --with-native-system-header-dir=/usr/include --with-sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
>   Thread model: posix
>   gcc version 9.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 9.2.0_1) `

Thank you.

Comment: How do you compile?

Comment: I compiled it like this.
`g++ test.cpp` or
`g++ -o test test.cpp`

Comment: Did you install Apple Command Line Tools for Xcode?

Comment: Works on my machine, but I have to use `g++-9` not `g++`.

Comment: It might be a path issue e.g. the gcc managed by command line tools appears in your PATH before the one installed by homebrew. See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245891/installed-gcc-with-homebrew-now-how-to-use-that-gcc-instead-of-clang

Comment: I added symbolic link like `ln -s /usr/local/bin/g++-9 /usr/local/bin/g++`.
And I added `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` to  bash_profile.
I also added alias as the link you mentioned.

Comment: It looks like the sysroot is set to the command line tools SDK. Try compiling with `--sysroot=/` e.g. `g++ --sysroot=/ -o test test.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

To conclude, the error solved by updating Xcode.
Thank you for your help.

As you commented, I tried to `g++ --sysroot=/ -o test test.cpp`,
then I got a new error such as

> fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
>    #include 
>            ^~~~~~~~~

Also I tried to compile the code having only `int main(){}` without any library. Then this was succeeded.

From this, I understood there is a problem related in standard library.
This problem sometimes happened discussed at [Can't compile C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave).

Anyway, the solution for this kind of problem seemes to be updating or reinstalling Xcode or gcc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your error log: `file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)`

I guess you should reinstall your gcc & g++ with command: `arch -x86_64 brew install gcc`, which will install them in x86_64 architecture.