# Problem with C++ compiler on macOS (building cmake project)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I have a 16inch MacBook pro with latest updates (macOS Catalina 10.15.2 (19C57)), the latest version of XCode and Command line tools for macOS (the tools being installed in the usual path /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/).. Not sure if this is relevant to my issue or not, but I also have the latest version of JetBrains’s CLion installed on my machine (running without issues).

**Here is the problem:** When trying to build a project with cmake, the build FAILS, giving me this error message:

```
In file included from /Users/basavyr/Pipeline/DevWorkspace/Github/xrootd/bindings/python/src/PyXRootDFile.cc:25:
In file included from /Users/basavyr/Pipeline/DevWorkspace/Github/xrootd/bindings/python/src/PyXRootD.hh:28:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:38:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string.h:61:15: fatal error: 
      'string.h' file not found
#include_next <string.h>
1 error generated.
error: command '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc' failed with exit status 1
make[2]: *** [bindings/python/python_bindings] Error 1
make[1]: *** [bindings/python/CMakeFiles/python_target.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

and this is probably related to my C++ compiler not having the correct path to the include files. To see what the issue could be, I’ve made a simple C++ file and I tried to compile it.

> main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string name = "NAMEX";
    std::cout << name;
}
```

First, I tried with the usual “g++” and it worked just fine:

```
basavyr@Roberts-MacBook-Pro stringTestCLANG % g++ main.cpp 
basavyr@Roberts-MacBook-Pro stringTestCLANG % ./a.out 
NAMEX%                                                                                                                basavyr@Roberts-MacBook-Pro stringTestCLANG %
```

Then, I tried with `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ main.cpp` and it worked just fine. 
Checking the version of “g++” on my machine gives me this:

```
g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

This is interesting, because I was expecting that the *default* compiler is installed in `/usr/bin/` instead. Going into that “InstalledDir” folder I saw that there is no “g++” binary, but only “clang++” and “c++”, so I tried to compile with both and it turns out that both compilers are giving the same error as the one in the project that I trying to build:

```
basavyr@Roberts-MacBook-Pro stringTestCLANG % /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:505:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:176:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:642:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:61:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string.h:61:15: fatal error: 
      'string.h' file not found
#include_next <string.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
basavyr@Roberts-MacBook-Pro stringTestCLANG %
```

Since I also have Command Line Tools installed, I tried to compile with both “g++” and “clang++” from `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/` and the first one compiles successfully, while the second one throws the same error with regards to the string header file.

```
basavyr@Roberts-MacBook-Pro stringTestCLANG % /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:505:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:176:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:642:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:61:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string.h:61:15: fatal error: 'string.h' file not found
#include_next <string.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

So, I assume that when I build that project with cmake, it is using one of these compilers (from the XCodeDefault.xctoolchain folder) and it has issues with the string header.

**Q1:** How can I solve this issue? **Q2:** And also, why does my “g++” installation directory points to this XCodeDefault.xctoolchain instead of “/usr/bin/’ or “/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/”. Is there a way to change that in macOS?

Thank you in advance

Comment: First of all, congratulations for having a 16inch MacBook pro. Can you check that answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't compile C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave)

Comment: @OnurTuna thank you haha! Let me have a look on the post and I will get back to you.