# Building gnu/opensource (C) projects in macOS Mojave

Tags: c, xcode, macos, include, macos-mojave

It's been awhile since I've tried to do this, maybe 3 or 4 years already. It was largely trivial then, download the tarball. Open it up, configure, make, and make install.

I do have Xcode installed, and I have the Xcode command line tools as well. Up to date. But when I run make, it complains about "error.h file not found".

Given how Apple has since locked the operating system down, it's not as simple as symlinking a directory for the includes. Or, if it is, I can't figure out where to begin with that.

The project is unavailable with homebrew, or I'd be lazy and do that.

The output is as follows:

```
omelo:ccd2cue-0.5 john$ sudo make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in po
Making all in src
  CC       ccd2cue.o
ccd2cue.c:58:10: fatal error: 'error.h' file not found
#include <error.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [ccd2cue.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What do I need to fix in my environment so that this can build?

Comment: On Mojave, you need to install the command line tools for Xcode.  If you list `/usr/include`, it might not exist or it might be empty. On Catalina, you have to set `CPATH` environment variable to the correct location.  See also [Can't compile a C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52530212/15168).

Comment: Do you have Gnulib? I think that program needs it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, that answer led to another that solved my problem.

Comment: In case you depend on gnu stuff, you can always build whole build chain by yourself: https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-9-2-0/ and even have a nice env setup with modules so you can easily jump between releases: https://www.owsiak.org/modules-as-a-convenient-way-of-choosing-build-chain-on-macos/