# _ctermid.h not found on macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew

On  **macOS Mojave 10.14.6** (18G7016), `gcc` can't find the file `_ctermid.h` anymore

```
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h:90,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/include/c++/10.2.0/cwchar:44,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:40,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/include/c++/10.2.0/string:40,
                 from /Users/Projects/test.h:10,
                 from /Users/Projects/test.cpp:1:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/lib/gcc/10/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/10.2.0/include-fixed/stdio.h:219:10: fatal error: _ctermid.h: No such file or directory
  219 | #include <_ctermid.h>
```

This was either caused by a macOS software update or `brew upgrade`.

This is might be related to an older question [Can't compile C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave/52530212#52530212).

I tried the suggested solutions:

- deleting the whole `CommandLineTools` folder with `(sudo) rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and reinstalled it `xcode-select --install`
- installed the `macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14` with `open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`
- reinstalled `brew` and `gcc` (also `gcc@9` and `gcc@8`)

None of them worked.

Comment: `brew doctor` says: ```Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you an update run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install```
The latter is what I did already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, `xcode-select --install` does not install the most recent Command Line Tools for macOS 10.14 (Mojave).

It always installs the version for Xcode 10.

To fix the issue, download and install [*Command Line Tools for Xcode 11.3.1*](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.3.1/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.3.1.dmg). That’s the most recent version of the CLT that still work for Mojave.

In case the direct link above doesn’t work, go to [“More Downloads for Apple Developers”](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/), log in with an Apple Developer account, and search for “Command Line Tools for Xcode 11.3.1”. Note that this is *not* the most recent version of the CLT, but more recent versions can’t be installed on Mojave.

Comment: The direct link did not work, so I had to log in as you described. Now, with CLT for Xcode 11.3.1 it works again like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: May the StackOverflow gods smile upon thee. My problem is solved.